# Não consigo importar a lib aacdecoder corretamente

Tags: android, android-studio

Apesar de eu ja ter descompactado o conteúdo da lib tanto na pasta libs, quanto na pasta jniLibs, não consigo importar as classes. Já dei rebuild.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Desde já, obrigado.

**UPDATE** -> gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.informatheus.radiodasantigaschat"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'org.pircbotx:pircbotx:2.0.1'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: Acho que basta adicionar o **jar** e as bibliotecas nativas na pasta `libs`, não precisa estar também na pasta `jniLibs`. Outra coisa que precisa verificar é se adicionou a configuração `sourceSets` no `build.gradle`. Poderia também incluir o `build.gradle`?

Comment: atualizei. obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha sugestão é a seguinte:

1) Remover as bibliotecas nativas da pasta `libs`, deixando-as apenas na pasta `jniLibs`.

2) Remover o jar do `aacdecoder` da pasta `jniLibs`, deixando-o apenas na pasta `libs`.

Uma boa prática é usar a pasta `jniLibs` para bibliotecas nativas e a `libs` para bibliotecas Java/Android.

Comment: Pode me explicar o que são bibliotecas nativas e não nativas?
Desculpe mas não entendi muito bem a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @Informatheus, bibliotecas nativas são aquelas escritas especificas para determinadas plataformas/arquiteturas, por exemplo MIPS, ARM, X86, e em geral são escritas em C/C++, as vezes assembly. Elas usam instruções especificas do processador para maior ganho de performance, acesso a certas funcionalidades, etc... No seu caso é a biblioteca do *decoder*, que estão na pasta jniLibs. A biblioteca não nativa é o jar, que faz a interface (fornecendo uma API) entre as bibliotecas nativas e seu aplicativo.

Comment: Acho que agora está tudo certo. Qualquer coisa eu volto.
Mto obrigado. Abraços.

Comment: Só pra completar, tive que clicar com o botão direito sobre o .jar e selecionar "Add as library".
Depois disso deu certo.